# lost value of object in c++ sqlite callback function

Tags: c++, sqlite

these are the functions, after building the correct object inside **fillAlbum** data gets lost in **openAlbum**.

```
/*
the function will fill the album with correct values (callback function)
*/
int fillAlbum(void* data, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName)
{
    Album* album = new Album();
    album->setName(argv[1]);
    album->setCreationDate(argv[3]);
    album->setOwner(std::stoi(argv[2]));
    data = album;

    return 0;
}

/*
the function return the asked album
*/
Album DatabaseAccess::openAlbum(const std::string& albumName)
{
    Album album;
    char** errMessage = nullptr;
    std::string sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM ALBUMS WHERE NAME LIKE '" + albumName + "';";
    sqlite3_exec(db_access, sqlStatement.c_str(), fillAlbum, &album, errMessage);
    return album;
}
```

Comment: Please make a [mre] for both, the C++ code and the SQLite database. Read the sqlite tag info to learn how. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Assigning to a function's (non-reference) argument  - `data = album;` - has no effect outside the function. There is nothing special about pointers.

Comment: Use a [prepared statement](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/stmt.html) instead of `sqlite3_exec()` if you want to use the results of a query for anything other than printing.

Comment: @Shawn Indeed... my new album is going to be called `'; DROP ALBUMS; --` (obligatory [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/327/)).

Comment: @TripeHound Produced by Bobby Tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gets lost (in fact it is worse: you have a memory leak!) because you don't use the callback correctly. You pass `&album` and now you have to **cast** the `void*` pointer and **fill it**, not **overwrite it** (in fact, the `data = album` line has no effect at all outside the `fillAlbum` function, you just overwrite a local variable). Try this:

```c
int fillAlbum(void* data, int argc, char** argv, char** azColName)
{
    Album* album = static_cast<Album*>(data);  // <-- this line is crucial
    album->setName(argv[1]);
    album->setCreationDate(argv[3]);
    album->setOwner(std::stoi(argv[2]));
    return 0;
}
```